# How can I analyze sound output in Python?

Tags: python, audio, output, soundcard

Is it possible to get the system output audio (the exact same thing that goes through the speakers) and analyze it in real time with Python? My intention is to build a sound visualizer. I know that it is possible to access the microphone with pyaudio, but I was not able to access the sound card output in any way, I'm looking for a solution  that works on Windows.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Hope you have looked at https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this project is doing these days, it's been a long time since it's been updated. PyVST allows you to run python code in a VST inside a VST host, which makes it possible to handle realtime audio events.

You might want to look at http://code.google.com/p/pyo/ for some ideas about how to handle DSP data as well.